# ASP.NET / XAML User Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Below is an example of a user interface I am tasked to create either in ASP.net or XAML
[image]

The intent is to create a UI as shown below with 55 total boxes.  Each box is associated with each component.  For example, #16 is between Requirements and Tools.  When clicking on the number, it will be redirected to a new page.

1) Is this best done using an ASP.net page or XAML?
2) When hovering over a number it should turn to red.

Comment: XAML or ASP.NET , depends on whether you want web application or stand alone desktop application. Which one you want? What code you have written for this?

Comment: UI tools are flexible enough to create something like this. The question is more of which one are you more comfortable with.

Comment: I'm leaning towards ASP.net.  Essentially, the image above will be on the main home page and that is it.  Clicking on any number will be redirected to a new tab/page.  I'm not sure if there is a similar example as to what I'm intending to develop.